# JasperReports: add List of images to PDF document

Tags: java, list, pdf, collections, jasper-reports

I am generating PDF documents. It is OK. All works.

I have only one problem: on each PDF page I need about 10 images (QR codes). Is it possible to
put List of java.awt.Image to JasperReport template? Put each image in separate field is complicated...
Example:

[image]

In template I have image components with these settings (http://goo.gl/wcESGp):

```
Expression Class: java.awt.Image
Image Expression :
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
     new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
         $F{CONTENT_TO_ENCODE},
         com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300))
```

One image is no problem - just set field in template and put image to field in Java code. How can I fill images in *JasperReports* report template with List<Image>?